# Magento2: How to call js function in custom file

Tags: magento2.2, knockoutjs, requirejs

I want to call a particular third party js function in my custom js file.

**XXX/YYY/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method.js.**

```
define([
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ], function (Component) {
        'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'XXX_YYY/payment/cashondelivery'
        },

        /**
         * Returns payment method instructions.
         *
         * @return {*}
         */
        getInstructions: function () {
            //some code here
        },
        getCodFeeInstruction: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.codfee_msg;
        }
    });
});
```

I need to call getInstructions() in my custom js file.

**In my custom file:**

**AAA/ZZZ/js/view/payment/method-renderer/online-method.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    'mage/url',
    'XXX_YYY/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method'
], function ($, Component, url, payment) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('online');
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'AAA_ZZZ/payment-methods/onlinepayment',

        },       

        getPreparePayment: function () {
            console.log("asd");
            payment.getInstructions();
        }
    });
});
```

But it returns **payment.getInstructions is not a function** error in console.

How to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just create or edit requirejs-config.js file from below path.

> /app/code/AAA/ZZZ/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

And place below code in requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
      'payment': 
          'XXX/YYY/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method'
    }
   }
};
```

Define this js in your custom file as :

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
'mage/url',
'payment'
]
```

Comment: Not working .... Its repeat same error

Comment: Delete static content and deploy static content.

Comment: Check your js is loading in requirejs in browser